# updating table based on count

Tags: sql, plsql

Is it possible to update the columns in table based on the count?. Suppose take in the table there are 2 similar records , based on where clause it returns 2 records.But how to restrict update statement only when count is 1,then only update the record otherwise not. Is it possible to do that?

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET column = x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(x) FROM x = 1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you can use a nested query in where clause which will return the record count which you can check if it is 0 or 1.

So it will be something likethis:

```
UPDATE table SET colName = x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table group by colName having colName =x) < =1;
```

Comment: is any other good way of doing this.using some kind of jdbc api ?

Comment: Well..jdbc is ultimately going to call a sql query, so you do need a query.